iOS 17.5.1 Xcode WebKit Crash
iOS 17.5.1 Xcode WebKit Crash
Hello, I have two iPhone devices that I have.
These devices are iOS17.5.1, and all Wk related codes cause Crash.
Crash occurs when Xcode Build is complete and the app is running. If you run without connecting to Xcode, Crash does not occur.
Error: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x19e88fa18)
Xcode 15.4, MacBook Pro 14 Sonoma 14.5
There was no issue with iOS 16.5.
WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
            .fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
                records
                    .forEach {
                        WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
                            .removeData(ofTypes: $0.dataTypes,
                                        for: [$0],
                                        completionHandler: {})
                    }
            }


let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true


are you sure you haven't just set a breakpoint in your code?  Check the breakpoint navigator in Xcode

@Paulw11 Thank you for your response. The location where I occurred was Apple's code, not mine.
I checked on the Apple Developer Forum and found that there were a few people who had the same problem as me.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/748008

@KimJitae the linked post seems to point to a workaround for the issue (and also a probable bug in WebKit itself) - have you tried said workaround? Seems like the only real solution will be for Apple to fix the bug in WebKit itself.

@DávidPásztor I disabled "Malloc Scribble" as shown in the link and no error occurred. I also agree that Apple has to fix this.

In my situation, I solved it as follows.
Open: Edit Scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics
Try disabling "Malloc Scribble" Or check out the Diagnostics-related options.
I solved the problem by disabling "Malloc Scribble".
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/748008
